# Unable to drop / select multiple columns in Shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, dashboard, dt

I'm using mtcars data for building shinyApp. I have put *checkboxgroupinput* for selecting columns like **cyl, vs, disp**.
But its currently not working. 
I have also put **column visibility of DT library** for the same purpose, but when i drop columns and download data, it shows the full output in excel.
I'm pasting my codes as well. Please have a look. Many thanks :)

data_table<-mtcars[,c(2,8,3,1,4,5,9,6,7, 10,11)]

```
  ncol(data_table)


  names(data_table)[4:11]<- rep(x = 
                                  c('OTS_lhr_Wave_1','OTS_isb_Wave_2','OTS_lhr_Wave_2','OTS_isb_Wave_1',                                                                            

                                    'NTS_lhr_Wave_1','NTS_isb_Wave_2','NTS_lhr_Wave_2','NTS_isb_Wave_1'), 
                                times=1, each=1) 




  library(readr)  
  library(shiny)   
  library(DT)     
  library(dplyr) 
  library(shinythemes) 
  library(htmlwidgets) 
  library(shinyWidgets) 



  ui = fluidPage( 
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel (


        downloadButton(outputId = "downLoadFilter",
                       label = "Download data"),






        selectInput(inputId = "disp",
                    label = "disp:",
                    choices = c("All",
                                unique(as.character(data_table$disp))),
                    selected = "All",
                    multiple = TRUE),





        radioButtons(inputId = "variables", label = "Choose Variable(s):",
                     choices =c("All","OTS", "NTS"), inline = FALSE,
                     selected = c("All")),



        selectInput(inputId = "regions1", label = "choose region",
                    choices =c("lhr"), 
                    multiple = TRUE,   selected = c("lhr")),


        selectInput(inputId = "regions2", label = "choose region",
                    choices =c("isb"), 
                    multiple = TRUE,   selected = c("isb")),




        selectInput(inputId = "waves", label = "choose wave",
                    choices =c("Wave_1", "Wave_2"), multiple  = TRUE,
                    selected = c("Wave_1", "Wave_2")),


        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "columns", label = "Select Columns to display:",
                           choices =names(data_table)[1:3],
                           selected = names(data_table)[1:3], inline = TRUE)

      ),




      mainPanel(
        tags$h5('Download only current page using following buttons:'),
        DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') )))







  server = function(input, output, session) {



    #tab 1
    thedata <- reactive({



      if(input$disp != 'All'){
        data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
      }



      #starting OTS NTS


      if  (input$variables== 'All'){
        data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                    names(data_table[grep(pattern = "TS", x = names(data_table), fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }




      if  (input$variables== 'OTS'){
        data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                    names(data_table[grep(pattern = "OTS", x = names(data_table), fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }



      if  (input$variables== 'NTS'){
        data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                    names(data_table[grep(pattern = "NTS", x = names(data_table), fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }






      #Region1
      all_cols <- names(data_table)
      region_cols <- c()




      if  ('lhr' %in% input$regions1){
        region_cols <- c(region_cols, all_cols[grep('lhr', all_cols, fixed = TRUE)])

      }  




      #Region2




      if  ('isb' %in% input$regions2){
        region_cols <- c(region_cols, all_cols[grep('isb', all_cols, fixed = TRUE)])

      }




      #Waves
      waves_cols <- c()


      if  ('Wave_1' %in% input$waves){
        waves_cols <- c(waves_cols, all_cols[grep('Wave_1', all_cols, fixed = TRUE)])
      }  

      if  ('Wave_2'  %in%  input$waves){
        waves_cols <- c(waves_cols, all_cols[grep('Wave_2', all_cols, fixed = TRUE)])
      }




      data_table <- data_table[,c( input$columns, intersect(region_cols, waves_cols)), drop=FALSE]







    })



    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

      DT::datatable( filter = "top",  rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                     class = 'cell-border stripe',
                     extensions = c('FixedHeader', 'Buttons'),
                     options = list(pageLength = 50, autowidth=FALSE, fixedHeader = TRUE, 
                                    dom = 'Brtip', 


                                    buttons = list('copy', 'print', 
                                                   list(extend = 'collection', 
                                                        buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'), 
                                                        text = 'Download'), 
                                                   list(extend = 'colvis', columns = c(0,1,2)))


                     ),
                     {     

                       thedata()   


                     }) 


    })




    output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('Filtered Data ', Sys.time(), '.csv', sep = '')
      },
      content = function(path){
        write_csv(thedata(), path)  # Call reactive thedata()
      }
    )




  }  


  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_table<-mtcars[,c(2,8,3,1,4,5,9,6,7, 10,11)]

  ncol(data_table)


  names(data_table)[4:11]<- rep(x = 

c('OTS_lhr_Wave_1','OTS_isb_Wave_2','OTS_lhr_Wave_2','OTS_isb_Wave_1',                                                                            


'NTS_lhr_Wave_1','NTS_isb_Wave_2','NTS_lhr_Wave_2','NTS_isb_Wave_1'), 
                                times=1, each=1) 




  library(readr)  
  library(shiny)   
  library(DT)     
  library(dplyr) 
  library(shinythemes) 
  library(htmlwidgets) 
  library(shinyWidgets) 



  ui = fluidPage( 
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel (


        downloadButton(outputId = "downLoadFilter",
                       label = "Download data"),






        selectInput(inputId = "disp",
                    label = "disp:",
                    choices = c("All",
                                unique(as.character(data_table$disp))),
                    selected = "All",
                    multiple = TRUE),





        radioButtons(inputId = "variables", label = "Choose Variable(s):",
                     choices =c("All","OTS", "NTS"), inline = FALSE,
                     selected = c("All")),



        selectInput(inputId = "regions1", label = "choose region",
                    choices =c("lhr"), 
                    multiple = TRUE,   selected = c("lhr")),


        selectInput(inputId = "regions2", label = "choose region",
                    choices =c("isb"), 
                    multiple = TRUE,   selected = c("isb")),




        selectInput(inputId = "waves", label = "choose wave",
                    choices =c("Wave_1", "Wave_2"), multiple  = TRUE,
                    selected = c("Wave_1", "Wave_2")),


        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "columns", label = "Select Columns to 
display:",
                           choices =names(data_table)[1:3],
                           selected = names(data_table)[1:3], inline = TRUE)

      ),




      mainPanel(
        tags$h5('Download only current page using following buttons:'),
        DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') )))







  server = function(input, output, session) {



    #tab 1
    thedata <- reactive({



      if(input$disp != 'All'){
        data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
      }



      #starting OTS NTS


      if  (input$variables== 'All'){
        data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                    names(data_table[grep(pattern = "TS", x 
= names(data_table), fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }




      if  (input$variables== 'OTS'){
        data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                    names(data_table[grep(pattern = "OTS", x 
= names(data_table), fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }



      if  (input$variables== 'NTS'){
        data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                    names(data_table[grep(pattern = "NTS", x 
= names(data_table), fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }






      #Region1
      all_cols <- names(data_table)
      region_cols <- c()




      if  ('lhr' %in% input$regions1){
        region_cols <- c(region_cols, all_cols[grep('lhr', all_cols, fixed = 
TRUE)])

      }  




      #Region2




      if  ('isb' %in% input$regions2){
        region_cols <- c(region_cols, all_cols[grep('isb', all_cols, fixed = 
TRUE)])

      }




      #Waves
      waves_cols <- c()


      if  ('Wave_1' %in% input$waves){
        waves_cols <- c(waves_cols, all_cols[grep('Wave_1', all_cols, fixed 
= TRUE)])
      }  

      if  ('Wave_2'  %in%  input$waves){
        waves_cols <- c(waves_cols, all_cols[grep('Wave_2', all_cols, fixed 
= TRUE)])
      }




      data_table <- data_table[,c( input$columns, intersect(region_cols, 
waves_cols)), drop=FALSE]







    })



    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({

      DT::datatable( filter = "top",  rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                     class = 'cell-border stripe',
                     extensions = c('FixedHeader', 'Buttons'),
                     options = list(pageLength = 50, autowidth=FALSE, 
fixedHeader = TRUE, 
                                    dom = 'Brtip', 


                                    buttons = list('copy', 'print', 
                                                   list(extend = 
'collection', 
                                                        buttons = c('csv', 
'excel', 'pdf'), 
                                                        text = 'Download'), 
                                                   list(extend = 'colvis', 
columns = c(0,1,2)))


                     ),
                     {     

                       thedata()   


                     }) 


    })




    output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('Filtered Data ', Sys.time(), '.csv', sep = '')
      },
      content = function(path){
        write_csv(thedata(), path)  # Call reactive thedata()
      }
    )




  }  


  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution based on your code that allows you to select and render specific columns based on your choice and downloads the column filtered data based on your choice.

The following changes were implemented to the code:

1. Dynamic choices were added to the `checkboxGroupInput()` in the form of

   - `checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "columns", 
                          label = "Select Columns to display:",
                          choices = data_table %>% colnames(),
                          selected = NULL)`
2. A reactive filtering method was written to return all of the selected columns based on the choices of (1) above as follows:

   - `columnFilter <- shiny::reactive({
     shiny::req(input$columns)
     data_table %>% select(input$columns)
     })`
3. A reactive download data preparation method was written which can be passed into the `downloadHandler()` as follows:

   - `getDownloadData <- shiny::reactive({
     if(is.null(input$columns)) return(thedata()) 
     else return(columnFilter())
     })`
4. Based in (3) above, the `downloadHandler()` now becomes:

   ```
    output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('Filtered Data ', Sys.time(), '.csv', sep = '')
     },
      content = function(path){
        write_csv(getDownloadData(), path)
     }
    )      
   }
   ```
5. In the data rendering function, a logical trigger was added as follows:

   - `if(is.null(input$columns)) thedata()
     else columnFilter()`
6. Everything else remained unchanged.

The full solution based on your code is below:

```
data_table<-mtcars[,c(2,8,3,1,4,5,9,6,7, 10,11)]

ncol(data_table)


names(data_table)[4:11]<- rep(x =                                 

                                c('OTS_lhr_Wave_1','OTS_isb_Wave_2','OTS_lhr_Wave_2','OTS_isb_Wave_1',                                                                            

                                  'NTS_lhr_Wave_1','NTS_isb_Wave_2','NTS_lhr_Wave_2','NTS_isb_Wave_1'), 
                              times=1, each=1) 


library(readr)  
library(shiny)   
library(DT)     
library(dplyr) 
library(shinythemes) 
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(shinyWidgets) 



ui <- fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel (


      downloadButton(outputId = 
                       "downLoadFilter",
                     label = "Download data"),




      selectInput(inputId = "cyl",
                  label = "cyl:",
                  choices = c("All",

                              unique(as.character(data_table$cyl))),
                  selected = "All",
                  multiple = TRUE),


      selectInput(inputId = "vs",
                  label = "vs:",
                  choices = c("All",

                              unique(as.character(data_table$vs))),
                  selected = "All",
                  multiple = TRUE),



      selectInput(inputId = "disp",
                  label = "disp:",
                  choices = c("All",  
                              unique(as.character(data_table$disp))),
                  selected = "All",
                  multiple = TRUE),

      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "columns", 
                         label = "Select Columns to display:",
                         choices = data_table %>% colnames(),
                         selected = NULL),

      radioButtons(inputId = "variables", 
                   label = "Choose Variable(s):",
                   choices =c("All","OTS", 
                              "NTS"), inline = FALSE,
                   selected = c("OTS")),



      selectInput(inputId = "regions", label = "choose region",
                  choices =c("lhr", 
                             "isb"), 
                  multiple = TRUE,   
                  selected = c("lhr")),




      selectInput(inputId = "waves", label =  "choose wave",
                  choices =c("Wave_1", 
                             "Wave_2"), multiple  = TRUE,
                  selected = c("Wave_1"))

    ),


    mainPanel(
      tags$h5('Download only current page using following 
              buttons:'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('mytable') )))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  columnFilter <- shiny::reactive({
    shiny::req(input$columns)
    data_table %>% select(input$columns)
  })

  getDownloadData <- shiny::reactive({
    if(is.null(input$columns)) return(thedata()) 
    else return(columnFilter())
  })

  #tab 1
  thedata <- reactive({

    if(input$cyl != 'All'){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$cyl,]
    }

    if(input$vs != 'All'){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$vs %in% input$vs,]
    }


    if(input$disp != 'All'){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$disp %in% input$disp,]
    }


    #starting OTS NTS


    if  (input$variables== 'All'){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                  names(data_table[grep(pattern = "TS", x = 
                                                          names(data_table), 
                                                        fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }


    if  (input$variables== 'OTS'){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                  names(data_table[grep(pattern = "OTS", x = 
                                                          names(data_table), 
                                                        fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }



    if  (input$variables== 'NTS'){
      data_table<-  data_table[,c("cyl", "vs", "disp" ,
                                  names(data_table[grep(pattern = "NTS", x = 
                                                          names(data_table), 
                                                        fixed = TRUE)])),drop=FALSE]    }


    #Region
    all_cols <- names(data_table)
    region_cols <- c("cyl", "vs", "disp" )


    if  ('lhr' %in% input$regions){
      region_cols <- c(region_cols, all_cols[grep('lhr', all_cols, fixed = 
                                                    TRUE)])

    }  
    if  ('isb' %in% input$regions){
      region_cols <- c(region_cols, all_cols[grep('isb', all_cols, fixed = 
                                                    TRUE)])

    }

    #Waves
    waves_cols <- c("cyl", "vs", "disp" )


    if  ('Wave_1' %in% input$waves){
      waves_cols <- c(waves_cols, all_cols[grep('Wave_1', all_cols, fixed = 
                                                  TRUE)])
    }  

    if  ('Wave_2'  %in%  input$waves){
      waves_cols <- c(waves_cols, all_cols[grep('Wave_2', all_cols, fixed = 
                                                  TRUE)])
    }


    data_table <- data_table[,intersect(region_cols, waves_cols), 
                             drop=FALSE]


  })

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable( filter = "top",  rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
                   class = 'cell-border stripe',
                   extensions = c('FixedHeader', 'Buttons'),
                   options = list(pageLength = 50, autowidth=FALSE, 
                                  fixedHeader = TRUE, 
                                  dom = 'Brtip', 


                                  buttons = list('copy', 'print', 
                                                 list(extend = 'collection', 
                                                      buttons = c('csv', 
                                                                  'excel', 
                                                                  'pdf'), 
                                                      text = 'Download'), 
                                                 list(extend = 'colvis', 
                                                      columns = c(0,1,2)))


                   ),
                   {
                     if(is.null(input$columns)) thedata()
                     else columnFilter()
                   }) 

  })


  output$downLoadFilter <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Filtered Data ', Sys.time(), '.csv', sep = '')
    },
    content = function(path){
      write_csv(getDownloadData(), path)
    }
  )

}      

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Screenshot below:
[image: Image of functional app]

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi mate, i tried using input$columns previously but it doesn't give required output

Comment: Hi @Doctor, I have managed to implement a solution. The above caters for what you need i.e. dynamic column filtering.

Comment: Hi mate, sorry for the late reply, thanks alot for the efforts that you put in. However the last 3 inputs of choose variable, choose region and choose waves isn't working. Can you pls have a look regards?

Comment: Hi @Doctor, I have tested and all is well on my end. I have added a screen shot to demonstrate that all data is being rendered based on choice. You can see that ihr and isb is there for both wave1 and wave2. I have testing all combinations, and they are functional.

Comment: Hi @Doctor did you manage to find out why the solution is not working on your end?

Comment: Hi mate, yes i came up with smth, i'll update my codes soon. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @Doctor, thanks man, please up vote so we can get the solution to this problem out there.

Comment: Hi @Rick, i have posted the solution, pls have a look. Thanks